# mysql booking reservation query

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause

I have the following data set:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars` (
  `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `car_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
INSERT INTO `cars` (`car_id`, `car_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Mercedes'),
(2, 'BMW');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_car_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_date_checkin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_date_dropoff` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`, `order_car_id`, `order_date_checkin`, `order_date_dropoff`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2018-01-17 10:00:00', '2018-01-19 21:00:00'),
(2, 1, '2018-01-22 14:00:00', '2018-01-25 17:00:00');
```

Simply I need to check if car is available on date range. I need this condition:

Don't return mercedes when

```
Check in date    Check out date
2018-01-16       2018-01-20
2018-01-17       2018-01-20
2018-01-17       2018-01-21
```

Return mercedes when:

```
Check in date    Check out date
2018-01-16       2018-01-16
2018-01-16       2018-01-17
2018-01-19       2018-01-21
2018-01-20       2018-01-21
2018-01-27       2018-01-30
```

My database is located on this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28a38d/1

Comment: For SQL problems, do include the information you have provided, but often times it is faster for people if you include a SQLFiddle (SQLFiddle.com) with the data structure + some dummy data setup.

Comment: the data in your SQL fiddle doesn't appear to reflect all the scenarios in your question. It would help everyone if it did.

Comment: ADyson i couldn't understand that where is the problem of my database? I think everything is correct by my side. If something is missing please let me know

Comment: Why doesn't it return BMW?

Comment: @AyxanƏmiraslanlı I meant that your SQLFiddle was not ready to use because the sample data you provided didn't cover all the possibilities you mentioned in the question, that's all. Anyway I see Strawberry did it for you and then solved it, so that's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rules;

CREATE TABLE rules
(rule_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,Check_in_date DATE NOT NULL
,Check_out_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO rules (Check_in_date,Check_out_date) VALUES
('2018-01-16','2018-01-20'),
('2018-01-17','2018-01-20'),
('2018-01-17','2018-01-21'),
('2018-01-16','2018-01-16'),
('2018-01-16','2018-01-17'),
('2018-01-19','2018-01-21'),
('2018-01-20','2018-01-21'),
('2018-01-27','2018-01-30');

SELECT c.*
     , r.* 
  FROM cars c 
  JOIN rules r 
  LEFT 
  JOIN orders o 
    ON o.order_car_id = c.car_id 
   AND o.order_date_checkin <= r.check_out_date -- may be you meant <
   AND o.order_date_dropoff >= r.check_in_date  -- may be you meant >
 WHERE o.order_id IS NULL;
+--------+----------+---------+---------------+----------------+
| car_id | car_name | rule_id | Check_in_date | Check_out_date |
+--------+----------+---------+---------------+----------------+
|      2 | BMW      |       1 | 2018-01-16    | 2018-01-20     |
|      2 | BMW      |       2 | 2018-01-17    | 2018-01-20     |
|      2 | BMW      |       3 | 2018-01-17    | 2018-01-21     |
|      1 | Mercedes |       4 | 2018-01-16    | 2018-01-16     |
|      2 | BMW      |       4 | 2018-01-16    | 2018-01-16     |
|      1 | Mercedes |       5 | 2018-01-16    | 2018-01-17     |
|      2 | BMW      |       5 | 2018-01-16    | 2018-01-17     |
|      2 | BMW      |       6 | 2018-01-19    | 2018-01-21     |
|      1 | Mercedes |       7 | 2018-01-20    | 2018-01-21     |
|      2 | BMW      |       7 | 2018-01-20    | 2018-01-21     |
|      1 | Mercedes |       8 | 2018-01-27    | 2018-01-30     |
|      2 | BMW      |       8 | 2018-01-27    | 2018-01-30     |
+--------+----------+---------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: `SELECT c.* FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON o.order_car_id = c.car_id 
AND o.order_date_checkin <= '2018-01-20'
AND o.order_date_dropoff >= '2018-01-18'
WHERE o.order_id IS NULL
ORDER BY `c`.`car_id` DESC;`

simply I updated your query and it worked